# How can I automatically run a command when I log out?

Tags: automation, session

I'd like to make a command run every time I log out. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are speaking of logging out of a bash login shell, there's a solution with `~/.bash_logout` — Run `man bash` in the terminal for more details.

If you are speaking of logging out of the X-window system, there are far too many ways to get yourself "logged out" for there to be any way to guarantee the command will run.

However, since you are the one doing the logging out, if you change your logout habit, this might work...

If you are running gnome, you might want to write a short script - maybe called "logo" - put it in `~/bin` (and ensure `~/bin` is in your PATH).

The "logo" script would do two things:

1. Run whatever command you want to run when you logout.
2. Run `gnome-session-save` with your choice of arguments.

Run `man gnome-session-save` in the terminal for more details on the arguments.